# Do Button events in Android really have to be explicitly disabled?

Tags: android, button

So I'm new to Android and have this wee app that has a variety of Buttons. The buttons do a variety of things, but of particular interest are the buttons that intent to another activity.

Because as I'm happily programming and testing along, I discover that I can double- and sometimes triple-tap these buttons.

I look for methods on the Button object that will allow me to specify the number of clicks that the button is allowed or whether the button should be (even briefly) disabled after a click. I find nothing of the sort.

Incredulous, I begin googling for a high-level discussion of this strange behavior. I find no interesting discussions, just suggestions about how to handle the issue on every single button in my app.

With a heavy sigh, I surrender to the time demands of my project, and add private variables to my activities (no static locals in Java. crap.), which the click-handling method uses to tell whether it's already busy handling a button click.

But still I wonder. **Do Button events in Android *really* have to be explicitly disabled?**

**Edit:** I'm looking for an answer of the form: "Yes (or no), and I know they have to be explicitly disabled because X".

Comment: `(no static locals in Java. crap.)`  That's a matter of opinion.  There is a good reason why C# and Java do not support such anti-pattern monstrosities.  If you really must, just use a static class field.  Why not extend the `Button` class, add whatever functionality you want, an use that class everywhere?

Comment: `Do Button events in Android really have to be explicitly disabled?`  I've tried to understand the reasoning behind this question and I must admit I can't see it.  A button, by it's very nature, will generate an event each time it is clicked.  How you respond, or do not respond, to such events is entirely your choice.  Why would the base class determine such behaviour?

Comment: What makes you think that this behavior is "strange"? I have been developing GUIs since the late 1980's, and I cannot think of any GUI framework that I have encountered that assumed that a push-button would only support a single click.

Comment: @Simon, Yes, definitely. Now that you mention it, it's obvious that extending the button class is what I should have done. I was just a little surprised that this little bit of functionality wasn't provided by the framework, and hoped that the SO community could confirm that yes, this is how the Android framework works, and possibly point me to some wise discussion of the rationale that I hadn't yet managed to find on my own.

Comment: @CommonsWare, go ahead and ignore me, thanks. I'm probably just being unreasonable.

Comment: I don't think you will find any rationale since this is normal behaviour for a button.  I agree with CommonsWare.  I've worked with many different GUI frameworks and have yet to see one that behaves as you wish.

Comment: So I went back and looked to be sure: winforms, delphi VCL and iOS all do something about the number of taps or clicks on their Button object (and the default is single). Plus, if you peek at the SO responses regarding how to provide double-tap handling in iOS, you'll notice that several of those folks also find multiple-tapping on a button a strange UI behavior, much less a default. I think that means that even if I'm dumb, I'm not straight crazy.

Answer (score 1):

The platform can't assume you only want to allow the button to be clicked once, or how frequently you should be able to click it. Just add logic to disable the button once you've clicked it, e.g.:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {
        v.setEnabled(false);
        //Do other stuf
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, the platform /could/ assume that, couldn't it, and disable the button briefly after one tap? Sure, that might not be the perfect behavior for every button, so the platform designer might want to add an option like "numberOfTapsRequired", but it seems like one tap would be a relatively sane default behavior.

Comment: I don't agree, honestly. Framework behaviors should be as unassuming and generic as they can be. If you want it to only be clickable once, it's up to you to determine when you can and cannot click it again.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, frameworks need to be generic. I guess I'm not surprised that multiple taps is the default. But I am surprised that the framework doesn't provide any built-in way to request that behavior, and that I couldn't find any discussion of this question anywhere. I must conclude that I'm just being unreasonable.

Comment: I can certainly see why you would want the behavior (trust me, I've been caught off guard more than once forgetting to disable a button after a click event), so I wouldn't call it unreasonable. I just wouldn't expect it as default behavior.